# Find out which of four variables contains the largest integer in javascript

Tags: javascript, integer

I have four variables, a, b, c, and d, which each contain a number between **0 and 100**, and I don't know the code to determine which one of the four variable contains the largest number.

I need to know the name of the variable that holds the highest value, not the highest value itself!

Comment: can you show some code scratch that you done until now ?

Comment: What if there’s more than one varibable with the highest value? What do you mean by _determining the variable_ that has the highest value? You mean just the value, right? Use `Math.max(a, b, c, d)`.

Comment: `Object.entries({ a, b, c, d}).sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1]).pop()[0]`

Comment: the data is in http://www.redshadow67.com/deepest/js/scor.js  with run, uun, gun, and kun being the ones I want to check. (which of the four characters' combined data scores is highest so I know which one takes the initiative in the scene)

Comment: I ended up doing this, but I still would like to know for when I have 20 variables or something....    function startScared2(){ if(run>uun&&run>gun&&run>kun){dragon2="red"; redAct();} if(uun>run&&uun>gun&&uun>kun){dragon2="blue"; blueAct();} if(gun>run&&gun>uun&&gun>kun){dragon2="green"; greenAct();} if(kun>run&&kun>uun&&kun>gun){dragon2=="black"; blackAct();} }

Comment: plus it doesn't send them anywhere if one equals the other, for that matter. Needs a check for that too

Answer (score 3):

```js
let a=8, b=1, c=9, d=3

let obj={a,b,c,d},
 greatest=Object.values(obj).sort().pop()
 key = Object.keys(obj).find( k => obj[k] === greatest )

console.log(key) // Logs "c"
```

Comment: If I update the value of b as 10, the ouput is still "c".

Answer (score 2):

> Check out this, worked for me...

```
Math.max(a, b, c, d);
```

Comment: This just finds the greatest value, not the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code. This also works for the negative integers, in case you have negative values in future. It will be useful for you.

```js
var a=10, b=20, c=15, d = 5;
var array = [a, b, c, d];
var largest=a;

for (i=1; i<=array.length;i++){
    if (array[i]>largest) {
        largest=array[i];
    }
}
console.log(largest);
```

Comment: What if all the numbers are less than 0?

Comment: @Barmar to be fair.. OP does set the bounds as 0 to 100..

Comment: No worries, i have edited my answer to work with negative values as well

Comment: yes, this is what I was looking for...my brain just didn't want to cognate even well enough to ask the question apparently....

Comment: Please accept the answer and upvote if it was useful to you

Comment: no, this gave me the largest number, how do I figure out which variable that number is in. I have each variable getting number by calling this: function getRand(){outcome=Math.floor(Math.random()*rndnum);} and setting rndnum to 100. The four variables each called that function, and I then need to see which one is highest number so I can call the function that corresponds to that variable (red, blue, green, black, in essence)

Comment: something like: if red is largest, red(); if blue is largest, blue() etc.  If it was only two I'd do: if(red>green){red();} else {green();} but since there are four I thought there must be a better way to get which one is highest than to check them individually.

Comment: ps: it doesn't let me "upvote" quite yet, not enough brownie points

Comment: @RobinJoyWirth you can tick mark to green –

Comment: I got annoyed and just did this: function startScared2(){
if(run>uun&&run>gun&&run>kun){dragon2="red"; redAct();}
if(uun>run&&uun>gun&&uun>kun){dragon2="blue"; blueAct();}
if(gun>run&&gun>uun&&gun>kun){dragon2="green"; greenAct();}
if(kun>run&&kun>uun&&kun>gun){dragon2=="black"; blackAct();}
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive calls.
Store all the variables in an array. Initial call is by doing findMax(a, a.length-1).

```js
function findMax(a, index) {
  if (index > 0) {
    return Math.max(a[index], findMax(a, index - 1));
  } else {
    return a[0];
  }
}
var x = findMax([1, 4, 50, 3], 3);
console.log(x);
//In inital call pass array.length -1
```

Comment: `public static int` ? This is not even Javascript.

Comment: See now.Just change the code to javascript from java.Please upvote if you like my answer :)

Comment: `Store all the variables in an array`, you're not doing that in your code. Besides, I'm struggling to see what this function does. You're not even calling it or logging the output.

Answer (score -1):

Sort the array in descending order and get the first one.

```
[a, b, c, d].sort(function(num1, num2){return num2-num1;})[0]
```

Comment: This is not the point. You need to find THE VARIABLE, not the highest value.

Comment: @campovski What would _finding the variable_ mean if not _finding the value_?

Comment: Finding the variable name